# How to install the Wolfram Workbench plugin into Eclipse Kepler or Neon?

Tags: workbench, eclipse

Trying to install the Wolfram Workbench plugin into Eclipse Juno fails. How is it possible to install in into Eclipse Kepler ? Or Eclipse Neon?

Comment: It is actually possible to install it in Juno, I've done it before. I didn't like Juno though so I never tested it thoroughly... it might be unstable.

Comment: So what I meant to say was, if you really want to try then I'll probably be able to remember :)

Comment: Maybe others care? For me it does not matter that much. Kepler seems to work fine.

Comment: Could somebody comment on what the benefit is of installing into Eclipse vs. using the  standalone (branded) version of WB? (This is probably not a big/interesting enough question for the main site, this is why I'm asking in the comments)

Comment: @Ajasja Afaik, there have been no updates to the standalone version of Workbench. On the other hand Eclipse is actively being developed. So you can benefit from using newer Eclipse versions together with the plugin.

Comment: @Ajasja One reason to look into this was I did not succeed to install the git plugin [EGit](http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates) into the standalone version of Workbench.

Comment: This works fine on OS X 10.8.2, thanks Rolf. But what are the advantages of this version of Eclipse for Mathematica development?

Comment: For example you don't have to work around that strange update error you ran into (it's possible, but not nice). Also I just like the look of Kepler much more. And you can install Egit and other plugins which might not install well with Indigo (the Eclipse version WWB is based on).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Update October 2016: As mentioned [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/946075)** it is [officially documented](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221) how to install WWB into Eclipse Neon (64 bit)! Great! Thanx WRI.

This is tested on Windows and Linux:

1. Download and install **a 32bit version** of Eclipse Kepler from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
2. On Linux x86_64 make sure to have 32bit Java installed and configured, 
   and, e.g. on Fedora do:  yum install glibc.i686  libgcc.i686 gtk2.i686 libXtst.i686
3. Start Eclipse and go to Help/Install New Software
4. Click Add
5. Enter http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo for Location, Indigo for Name
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
6. Click OK and again Add and enter  http://workbench.wolfram.com/update
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
7. Wait a bit until you see
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
8. Install WWB core (and possibly WWB webMathematica), hit ok a couple of times
9. Don't forget to eventually adjust your location of Mathematica:
   [image: Mathematica graphics]
10. Here the About Eclipse box
    [image: Mathematica graphics]
11. And here the proof that it works:
    [image: Mathematica graphics]
12. One big productivity boost for me to use Eclipse is that there 
     are various vi plugins.
     One free possibility to use is [vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/update-site/stable) , another one (non-free)  is [viplugin](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin.htm)
    I also personally like [this](http://code.google.com/p/tarlog-plugins/) plugin which enables font-size changing by Crl++ and Ctrl+-

Comment: Maybe worth stressing that "The workbench 2.0 plugins will install into eclipse 3.4 - 3.8, but are not
compatible with 4.2" according to WRI.

Comment: This worked on OS X 10.8.2. However, the About box says 4.3.0, while the splash screen says "Juno" (which is 4.2)

Comment: Thanks for documenting this!  Just to clarify, are you using the 3.x or the 4.x series?  (It seems they're being developed in parallel at the moment.  I used 3.8 for Workbench.  If I understand it correctly, "Juno" could be either 4.2 or 3.8.)

Comment: (or even if both are not named Juno, they should have the same functionality)

Comment: @b.gatessucks As I said in a comment above, you can install the plugin in 4.x, you just have to jump through some hoops.

Comment: @sebhofer Could you please mention how to do it ? I use Fedora, which ships Eclipse 4.2; the Workbench plugin doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: @sebhofer Following your walkthrough on Win 7 I get the following error: 
An internal error occurred during: "FrontEnd Job::Open Notebook".
com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J

Comment: @b.gatessucks I did this a while ago and unfortunately I didn't make notes :( The point is that the workbench plugin requires 3 bundles which are not included in the new release. They are listed on [the release page](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/porting/4.2/incompatibilities.php). 1 one of them is just a dummy package which does nothing, the others can be installed if I remember correctly. I will try to remember what I did, but I don't have the time right now. I think the error messages during the install give a starting point.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig Even if you are on 64bit Windows you have to download the 32bit Eclipse version. Otherwise you get that NativeLink.MLOpenString error. Sorry, should have mentioned that earlier. Corrected now in the instructions.

Comment: What about in OS X (currently at 10.8.2): must one use the 32-bit Eclipse rather than he 64-bit version?

Comment: Although WRI lists just version 2.0 of Workbench, curiously the MacKeeper app has for some time indicated that it's out of date and that there's a version 2.1.6 available. Is the latter perhaps an internal-to-WRI version not yet released, or abandoned?

Comment: @murray I had to use the 32bit one too. The 64 bit just gave me a "file broken" error (or something like that).

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks so much for the clear instructions. (worked like a charm on Win7 machine). Am I correct in assuming the 32 vs 64 bit version of eclipse is really of little consequence? (it's really just whether or not eclipse itself is 32 or 64 bit, and has NO bearing on your ability to program/compile 64 bit programs, of course assuming you have the right 64 bit JDK installed.) I believe VS2012 is still only a 32 bit program. I mention/ask about this because I get the sense people are defaulting to a "64 bit is better mentality", when it really make no difference.

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 I didn't write the answer, Rolf Mertig did :)

Comment: @rm-rf - I'm always amused by these little data points about myself... Apparently my short term memory lasts about as long as this particular comment thread. :) Sooo... Thanks Rolf!

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 It does make a difference here. 32-bit Eclipse is mandatory.

Comment: @rm-rf I think something may have gotten fixed between then and now, because on Mac OS X 10.9.2 I was able to install Workbench into a 64 bit Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: With 4.x, you may have to first copy org.eclipse.core.boot and org.eclipse.update.ui jars to your eclipse/plugins/ folder. Get them from a 3.x release.

Comment: For Windows 7 64 bit, Java 1.7.24 64bit, I've installed eclipse 3.6.2 32bit and installed mathematica plugin as 'Rolf Mertig' described and everything is working perfect now. If you've problems with other versions of eclipse try eclipse 3.6.2

Comment: What is the difference between Wolfram Workbench and this one which can be installed on eclipse?

Comment: Great post, thank you for sharing with us. May I add the following :

If you are looking on how to install and configure 32 bit Java on a 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) machine, read the following comment  

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97161/18906

if you are looking on how to configure your 32 bit java execute the following command

   sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: @RolfMertig Did you get .nb files work in Eclipse Wolfram Workbench? I extended the thread to Ubuntu 16.04 here http://askubuntu.com/q/766993/25388

Comment: @Masi Yes. But Wolfram Research helped. Please contact the official Wolfram support. They are very friendly and helpful. I think a Wolfram Workbench 3 version will come to light soon. At least this has been the rumor for a couple of years.

Comment: Will the latest version of the plugin, dated 28 October 2016, work with the 64-bit version of Eclipse (Neon)? This is under macOS Sierra 10.12.1, which is of course a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @murray Yes, sure. Works fine.

Comment: @murray I've been running Neon on macOS 10.10.5 since before the conference. It is a nice upgrade. :)