# Installing Android ADT and Aptana studio plugins into Workbench

Tags: workbench, eclipse

My question is a *dual* to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18183/137).

I use Workbench 2.0, but I am now interested in developing some Android Apps and Html projects. 
In order to do that, I need to install Android ADT and Aptana studio plugins into Eclipse. 
Questions:

- Since Workbench is based on Eclipse I wonder if I can install these plugins into WB.
- Is it possible and/or wiser to simply install a (newer) version of Eclipse in a parallel folder and install the plugins into this Eclipse? Would this interfere somehow with the existing Workbench?

I realize this question is not strictly about Mathematica, but I believe it might be of some interest for many Workbench users, as they explore other languages.

Comment: It's probably easier to use Eclipse directly and install the Workbench plugin into it.  Use the 3.8 version of Eclipse, not the 4.2 one.  Workbench is not compatible with the 4-series.  Advantages of using Eclipse are: newer version, and being able to ask for help from Eclipse people (they won't say, "what is this weird thing called Workbench, why don't you use standard Eclipse?")

Comment: I understand this @Szabolcs, that is why I asked if it is possible to have WB and Eclipse living together on the same machine. I already have WB working well with my projects, I prefer not to uninstall it and get the WB plugin