# Error trying to open a notebook in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench, java

I recently set up Mathematica 9.0.1 on a new computer, along with x64 Eclipse Indigo with JRE 1.7, and the Wolfram Workbench 2 plug-in. Something is amiss, because when I try to do any sort of task involving Mathematica from inside Workbench, I get the same error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "FrontEnd Job::Open Notebook".
 com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

Otherwise, Mathematica works fine, as does the Eclipse install when used for other purposes (Java and Scala development).

This is a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.

Comment: have you tried installing Wokrbench as a standalone application?

Comment: Isn't it connected with 64 bit and java? (I know similar issue from Linux system)

Comment: at the moment, i'd really prefer to keep using Indigo if at all possible.

Comment: For me, Eclipse 3.7.2 is the latest version supporting the workbench plugin.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I'm currently using Eclipse 3.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18183/how-to-install-the-wolfram-workbench-plugin-into-eclipse-kepler) Rolf Mertig mentions that you have to use the 32 bit version of Eclipse.

(So I guess we can close this as a duplicate?)

I just installed WB into 32bit eclipse 3.7.2 on Win7 64bit and everything works great!

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I have found a way to avoid a 32-bit re-installation of Eclipse, based on help from Wolfram support. Would it be inappropriate to add it either here, or to the other question?

Comment: @Pillsy Hmm good question. I would definitely add this somewhere! You can't add it here (right now) as we would first have to reopen the question. I guess you can add it as an answer to the other question. Then it can be moved by the admins if necessary.

Comment: related http://software.additive-net.de/en/support/wolfram-support/wolfram-faq-installation/3747-workbench64 (you'll need to translate from german)