# Wolfram Workbench 2.0 on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS trusty

Tags: linux, workbench, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Wolfram Workbench on Xubuntu 14.04 but the apptication doesn't start.

Knowing that WWb is a 32 bit application, I installed the i386 requrements:

```
ii  gcc-4.8-base:i386                         4.8.2-19ubuntu1                        i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:i386                         4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1                  i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libc6:i386                                2.19-0ubuntu6                          i386         Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-i386                                2.19-0ubuntu6                          amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libgcc1:i386                              1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1                i386         GCC support library
ii  libgpm2:i386                              1.20.4-6.1                             i386         General Purpose Mouse - shared library
ii  libncurses5:i386                          5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                  i386         shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libstdc++6:i386                           4.8.2-19ubuntu1                        i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libtinfo5:i386                            5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                  i386         shared low-level terminfo library for terminal handling
```

but when I run /usr/local/bin/WolframWorckbench the process start and stop after 1 second !

So checked with ldd:

```
root@lua:/opt/WolframWorkbench/2.0# ldd WolframWorkbench
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf777d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf774a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7745000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7595000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf777e000)
```

If I check the execution with strace I can see a lot of errors on some system call:

```
root@lua:/usr/local/bin# strace -c /usr/local/bin/WolframWorkbench 
[ Process PID=18919 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 26.56    0.000192          21         9           clone
 14.11    0.000102           6        18           read
 13.42    0.000097          11         9           wait4
 11.48    0.000083           4        21           close
  5.67    0.000041           5         9           pipe
  4.84    0.000035           5         7           mmap
  4.01    0.000029           3         9           rt_sigreturn
  2.77    0.000020           5         4           mprotect
  2.63    0.000019           6         3           open
  2.35    0.000017           2         7           rt_sigaction
  2.07    0.000015           5         3         3 access
  1.94    0.000014           5         3           brk
  1.80    0.000013           4         3           stat
  1.11    0.000008           8         1           munmap
  1.11    0.000008           4         2           chdir
  0.83    0.000006           3         2           fstat
  0.83    0.000006           3         2           fcntl
  0.83    0.000006           3         2           geteuid
  0.55    0.000004           4         1           faccessat
  0.41    0.000003           3         1           getpid
  0.41    0.000003           3         1           arch_prctl
  0.28    0.000002           2         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           execve
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000723                   120         3 total
System call usage summary for 32 bit mode:
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 43.11    0.034557           3     10561           gettimeofday
 15.03    0.012050           4      2803           read
 12.63    0.010124           3      3004           _llseek
  8.84    0.007088          12       583        19 futex
  5.88    0.004711           4      1103       197 stat64
  4.77    0.003821           6       693       513 open
  1.46    0.001173           5       255        11 close
  1.18    0.000944           6       154           mmap2
  1.10    0.000879           4       222           fstat64
  1.00    0.000798          13        60           getdents64
  0.97    0.000774           4       173         1 lstat64
  0.96    0.000767          24        32           getdents
  0.57    0.000458           7        63           munmap
  0.57    0.000454           6        74           brk
  0.41    0.000325           7        50         3 openat
  0.23    0.000186          19        10           clone
  0.22    0.000177          20         9         3 unlink
  0.20    0.000157           7        23           mprotect
  0.17    0.000140           5        30        27 access
  0.17    0.000137           4        34           fcntl64
  0.14    0.000111           4        28           rt_sigaction
  0.06    0.000050          25         2           write
  0.04    0.000035           5         7           dup2
  0.04    0.000034           4         9           rt_sigprocmask
  0.04    0.000029          10         3           socket
  0.03    0.000021           5         4           getcwd
  0.02    0.000020          10         2         2 connect
  0.02    0.000019           5         4           uname
  0.02    0.000018          18         1           ftruncate
  0.02    0.000018           4         5           getrlimit
  0.02    0.000016          16         1           execve
  0.01    0.000010          10         1           socketpair
  0.01    0.000009           5         2           set_robust_list
  0.01    0.000008           4         2           set_thread_area
  0.01    0.000008           4         2           set_tid_address
  0.01    0.000007           4         2           clock_gettime
  0.01    0.000006           6         1           sched_yield
  0.01    0.000005           5         1         1 mkdir
  0.01    0.000005           5         1           getuid32
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           setrlimit
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           geteuid32
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           gettid
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           clock_getres
  0.00    0.000003           3         1         1 getsockname
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.080168                 20019       778 total
```

Perhaps I'm missing something? Do I need to install others i386 library?

Please can someone help me?

Comment: Try to use the Eclipse version instead of Workbench.  [(Instructions.)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18183/12)  First make sure you get 32-bit Eclipse working.  If it doesn't work, ask for help on an Eclipse forum, where people are more likely to be able to give you a solution quickly.  If you fix 32-bit Eclipse, check if it also fixes Workbench.  If it does, please report back here with the solution.

Comment: Ok now I try with eclipse plugin.

Comment: Yes, the eclipse plugin is a better solution, I suggest others try this first

Answer (score 3):

Resolved.

Seems I need more i386 library, here is the entire list:

```
 root@lua:/usr/local/bin# dpkg -l|grep i386
ii  gcc-4.8-base:i386                         4.8.2-19ubuntu1                        i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:i386                         4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1                  i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gtk2-engines-murrine:i386                 0.98.2-0ubuntu2                        i386         cairo-based gtk+-2.0 theme engine
ii  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386                  2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1                     i386         pixbuf-based theme for GTK+ 2.x
ii  libatk1.0-0:i386                          2.10.0-2ubuntu2                        i386         ATK accessibility toolkit
ii  libavahi-client3:i386                     0.6.31-4ubuntu1                        i386         Avahi client library
ii  libavahi-common-data:i386                 0.6.31-4ubuntu1                        i386         Avahi common data files
ii  libavahi-common3:i386                     0.6.31-4ubuntu1                        i386         Avahi common library
ii  libc6:i386                                2.19-0ubuntu6                          i386         Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-i386                                2.19-0ubuntu6                          amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libcairo2:i386                            1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1               i386         The Cairo 2D vector graphics library
ii  libcomerr2:i386                           1.42.9-3ubuntu1                        i386         common error description library
ii  libcups2:i386                             1.7.2-0ubuntu1                         i386         Common UNIX Printing System(tm) - Core library
ii  libdatrie1:i386                           0.2.8-1                                i386         Double-array trie library
ii  libdbus-1-3:i386                          1.6.18-0ubuntu4                        i386         simple interprocess messaging system (library)
ii  libexpat1:i386                            2.1.0-4ubuntu1                         i386         XML parsing C library - runtime library
ii  libffi6:i386                              3.1~rc1+r3.0.13-12                     i386         Foreign Function Interface library runtime
ii  libfontconfig1:i386                       2.11.0-0ubuntu4                        i386         generic font configuration library - runtime
ii  libfreetype6:i386                         2.5.2-1ubuntu2.1                       i386         FreeType 2 font engine, shared library files
ii  libgcc1:i386                              1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1                i386         GCC support library
ii  libgcrypt11:i386                          1.5.3-2ubuntu4                         i386         LGPL Crypto library - runtime library
ii  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386                   2.30.7-0ubuntu1                        i386         GDK Pixbuf library
ii  libglib2.0-0:i386                         2.40.0-2                               i386         GLib library of C routines
ii  libgnutls26:i386                          2.12.23-12ubuntu2                      i386         GNU TLS library - runtime library
ii  libgpg-error0:i386                        1.12-0.2ubuntu1                        i386         library for common error values and messages in GnuPG components
ii  libgpm2:i386                              1.20.4-6.1                             i386         General Purpose Mouse - shared library
ii  libgraphite2-3:i386                       1.2.4-1ubuntu1                         i386         Font rendering engine for Complex Scripts -- library
ii  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386                     1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4                     i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - krb5 GSS-API Mechanism
ii  libgtk2.0-0:i386                          2.24.23-0ubuntu1.1                     i386         GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libharfbuzz0b:i386                        0.9.27-1                               i386         OpenType text shaping engine (shared library)
ii  libjasper1:i386                           1.900.1-14ubuntu3                      i386         JasPer JPEG-2000 runtime library
ii  libjbig0:i386                             2.0-2ubuntu4.1                         i386         JBIGkit libraries
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:i386                       1.3.0-0ubuntu2                         i386         IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg8:i386                             8c-2ubuntu8                            i386         Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libk5crypto3:i386                         1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4                     i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Crypto Library
ii  libkeyutils1:i386                         1.5.6-1                                i386         Linux Key Management Utilities (library)
ii  libkrb5-3:i386                            1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4                     i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries
ii  libkrb5support0:i386                      1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4                     i386         MIT Kerberos runtime libraries - Support library
ii  liblzma5:i386                             5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2           i386         XZ-format compression library
ii  libncurses5:i386                          5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                  i386         shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libnspr4:i386                             2:4.10.2-1ubuntu1                      i386         NetScape Portable Runtime Library
ii  libnspr4-0d:i386                          2:4.10.2-1ubuntu1                      i386         NetScape Portable Runtime Library - transitional package
ii  libnss-mdns:i386                          0.10-6                                 i386         NSS module for Multicast DNS name resolution
ii  libnss-mdns-i386                          0.10-6                                 i386         NSS module for mDNS name resolution (i386 transitional package)
ii  libnss3:i386                              2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7                      i386         Network Security Service libraries
ii  libnss3-1d:i386                           2:3.15.4-1ubuntu7                      i386         Network Security Service libraries - transitional package
ii  libp11-kit0:i386                          0.20.2-2ubuntu2                        i386         Library for loading and coordinating access to PKCS#11 modules - runtime
ii  libpango-1.0-0:i386                       1.36.3-1ubuntu1                        i386         Layout and rendering of internationalized text
ii  libpango1.0-0:i386                        1.36.3-1ubuntu1                        i386         Layout and rendering of internationalized text
ii  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386                  1.36.3-1ubuntu1                        i386         Layout and rendering of internationalized text
ii  libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386                    1.36.3-1ubuntu1                        i386         Layout and rendering of internationalized text
ii  libpangox-1.0-0:i386                      0.0.2-4ubuntu1                         i386         pango library X backend
ii  libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386                    1.36.3-1ubuntu1                        i386         Layout and rendering of internationalized text
ii  libpcre3:i386                             1:8.31-2ubuntu2                        i386         Perl 5 Compatible Regular Expression Library - runtime files
ii  libpixman-1-0:i386                        0.30.2-2ubuntu1                        i386         pixel-manipulation library for X and cairo
ii  libpng12-0:i386                           1.2.50-1ubuntu2                        i386         PNG library - runtime
ii  libselinux1:i386                          2.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                       i386         SELinux runtime shared libraries
ii  libsqlite3-0:i386                         3.8.2-1ubuntu2                         i386         SQLite 3 shared library
ii  libstdc++6:i386                           4.8.2-19ubuntu1                        i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  libtasn1-6:i386                           3.4-3                                  i386         Manage ASN.1 structures (runtime)
ii  libthai0:i386                             0.1.20-3                               i386         Thai language support library
ii  libtiff5:i386                             4.0.3-7ubuntu0.1                       i386         Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library
ii  libtinfo5:i386                            5.9+20140118-1ubuntu1                  i386         shared low-level terminfo library for terminal handling
ii  libx11-6:i386                             2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2                       i386         X11 client-side library
ii  libxau6:i386                              1:1.0.8-1                              i386         X11 authorisation library
ii  libxcb-render0:i386                       1.10-2ubuntu1                          i386         X C Binding, render extension
ii  libxcb-shm0:i386                          1.10-2ubuntu1                          i386         X C Binding, shm extension
ii  libxcb1:i386                              1.10-2ubuntu1                          i386         X C Binding
ii  libxcomposite1:i386                       1:0.4.4-1                              i386         X11 Composite extension library
ii  libxcursor1:i386                          1:1.1.14-1                             i386         X cursor management library
ii  libxdamage1:i386                          1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1                       i386         X11 damaged region extension library
ii  libxdmcp6:i386                            1:1.1.1-1                              i386         X11 Display Manager Control Protocol library
ii  libxext6:i386                             2:1.3.2-1                              i386         X11 miscellaneous extension library
ii  libxfixes3:i386                           1:5.0.1-1ubuntu1                       i386         X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library
ii  libxft2:i386                              2.3.1-2                                i386         FreeType-based font drawing library for X
ii  libxi6:i386                               2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1                   i386         X11 Input extension library
ii  libxinerama1:i386                         2:1.1.3-1                              i386         X11 Xinerama extension library
ii  libxml2:i386                              2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.1                 i386         GNOME XML library
ii  libxrandr2:i386                           2:1.4.2-1                              i386         X11 RandR extension library
ii  libxrender1:i386                          1:0.9.8-1                              i386         X Rendering Extension client library
ii  libxslt1.1:i386                           1.1.28-2build1                         i386         XSLT 1.0 processing library - runtime library
ii  libxtst6:i386                             2:1.2.2-1                              i386         X11 Testing -- Record extension library
ii  zlib1g:i386                               1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1                  i386         compression library - runtime
```

Now Wolfram Workbench 2.0 32Bit works fine on Xubuntu_64Bit 14.04 LTS .

Please let me know if above info are useful.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Just got Workbench to work on 64 Bit Ubuntu 14.04 this way!

Answer (score 2):

First you have to install the Wolfram Workbench 2.0.0 for Linux.

```
./Workbench_2.0.0_LINUX.sh*
```

Then you have to find a way to execute the 32 bit program on a 64 bit Ubuntu machine

```
 WolframWorkbench
```

Normally it will crash see above to trace the execution....

I installed a 32 bit java on a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (trusty)

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk:i386
```

I also tried to overcome the obsolete installation of ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with these commands

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

and

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

A combination of the above worked in my case

You may also try to install these alternative 32 bit libraries before installing a 32 bit version of Eclipse Kepler

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Installing Wolfram Workbench on Eclipse Kepler is an alternative, better I think, solution that is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18184/18906)

Search more at Google with:

- enable 32-bit applications on Ubuntu 14.04
- How to run 32-bit applications on Ubuntu 64-bit
- Install 32bit Java on 64bit Ubuntu 14.04