# Debugging Test files generates exception in Workbench 2 and 3

Tags: workbench, testing-and-verification

I'm having trouble running the "test file" example given in the video here http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/workbench/WorkbenchTesterDemo/ in "Debug As...".

RUNning the test file "test.mt" (reproduced below on "myTest.m") generates the expected results:

```
(* myTest.m *)
(* Mathematica Package *)

(* Created by the Wolfram Workbench 15/10/2014 *)

BeginPackage["myTest`"]
(* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage *) 
fun::usage=""
fun2::usage=""

Begin["`Private`"]
(* Implementation of the package *)

fun[x_]:=Module[{y},
    y=x^2;
    y+1
]
fun2[x_]:=Module[{y},
    y+x^2;
    y+1
]

End[]

EndPackage[]


(* test.mt *)
(* Wolfram Language Test file *)

Test[
    fun[2]
    ,
    5
    ,
    TestID->"Test-20150824-R0J9T9"
]

Test[
    fun2[2]
    ,
    5
    ,
    TestID->"Test-20150824-I5E0I7"
]

Test[
    fun[2]
    ,
    5
    ,
    TestID->"Test-20150824-R5P1T6"
]
```

The bug appears to occur only in my Microsoft Windows 64-bit (Windows 8) versions of Workbench and not my home MacOSX versions.

Here is what I see:
(1) The unit tests all FAIL under DEBUG mode but the right ones PASS under RUN.

Here is the test error text cut and pasted from the MUnit console window:

```
Expected message list: 

{}



Actual message list: 

{Message[Java::excptn, MathLinkException: 7: MathLink machine number             overflow], Message[JavaNew::fail,     com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaStackFrame], Message[Java::argx,     handleBreakpoint, com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaBreakpointHandler,
{17285518212668119014, {Removed[JavaObject7074772890419201],         Removed[JavaObject10677862059212801], Removed[JavaObject3389761297317889],             Removed[JavaObject19526176968015873], Removed[JavaObject17482672817307649],         Removed[JavaObject8017039004270593], Removed[JavaObject13387682721824769],
Removed[JavaObject11935786123395073], Removed[JavaObject34304841085878273],     Removed[JavaObject35303688679456769], Removed[JavaObject34122984184610817],     Removed[JavaObject745498512195585], Removed[JavaObject18148307771588609],     Removed[JavaObject15029103677669377],
Removed[JavaObject19577584085893121], Removed[JavaObject29417674438082561],     Removed[JavaObject16850472690253825], Removed[JavaObject31391469323419649],     Removed[JavaObject26907565929529345], Removed[JavaObject9319986455642113],     Removed[JavaObject8782982567428097],
Removed[JavaObject16381811009519617], Removed[JavaObject35026857485139969],     Removed[JavaObject19426037909684225], Removed[JavaObject33061780880097281],     Removed[JavaObject31404466632654849], Removed[JavaObject2569195212505089],     Removed[JavaObject18586632538030081],
Removed[JavaObject33341953374420993], Removed[JavaObject34257782790160385],     Removed[JavaObject20128422432866305], Removed[JavaObject14505983019581441],     Removed[JavaObject33567107253796865], Removed[JavaObject22028935998996481],     Removed[JavaObject30846676696563713],
Removed[JavaObject7108060631793665], Removed[JavaObject26866341910675457],     $Failed, Removed[JavaObject3722139521777665],     Removed[JavaObject10184330554900481], Removed[JavaObject15229906854084609],     Removed[JavaObject10275074959474689], Removed[JavaObject15592187211284481],
Removed[JavaObject22155425554104321], Removed[JavaObject9089030394216449],     Removed[JavaObject34196997510529025], Removed[JavaObject35002742535618561],     Removed[JavaObject35646965198880769], Removed[JavaObject6776183542775809],     Removed[JavaObject1394708806893569],
Removed[JavaObject1631293657841665], Removed[JavaObject19127489783660545],     Removed[JavaObject1823792011673601], Removed[JavaObject10028269680197633],     Removed[JavaObject3591463682179073], Removed[JavaObject11334475619237889],     Removed[JavaObject13425338293944321],
Removed[JavaObject33336335439757313], Removed[JavaObject31157552368582657],     Removed[JavaObject9682765297483777], Removed[JavaObject29697961487237121],     Removed[JavaObject24748448825737217], Removed[JavaObject783825693048833],     Removed[JavaObject24748124924805121]},
False}]}

Expected output: 

5



Actual output: 

1 + myTest`Private`y$2676

Third Test (fails again though it should pass)


Expected message list: 

{}



Actual message list: 

{Message[Java::excptn, MathLinkException: 7: MathLink machine number overflow], Message[JavaNew::fail, com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaStackFrame], Message[Java::argx, handleBreakpoint, com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaBreakpointHandler,
{17285518212668119014, {Removed[JavaObject7074772890419201], Removed[JavaObject10677862059212801], Removed[JavaObject3389761297317889], Removed[JavaObject19526176968015873], Removed[JavaObject17482672817307649], Removed[JavaObject8017039004270593], Removed[JavaObject13387682721824769],
Removed[JavaObject11935786123395073], Removed[JavaObject34304841085878273], Removed[JavaObject35303688679456769], Removed[JavaObject34122984184610817], Removed[JavaObject745498512195585], Removed[JavaObject18148307771588609], Removed[JavaObject15029103677669377],
Removed[JavaObject19577584085893121], Removed[JavaObject29417674438082561], Removed[JavaObject16850472690253825], Removed[JavaObject31391469323419649], Removed[JavaObject26907565929529345], Removed[JavaObject9319986455642113], Removed[JavaObject8782982567428097],
Removed[JavaObject16381811009519617], Removed[JavaObject35026857485139969], Removed[JavaObject19426037909684225], Removed[JavaObject33061780880097281], Removed[JavaObject31404466632654849], Removed[JavaObject2569195212505089], Removed[JavaObject18586632538030081],
Removed[JavaObject33341953374420993], Removed[JavaObject34257782790160385], Removed[JavaObject20128422432866305], Removed[JavaObject14505983019581441], Removed[JavaObject33567107253796865], Removed[JavaObject22028935998996481], Removed[JavaObject30846676696563713],
Removed[JavaObject7108060631793665], Removed[JavaObject26866341910675457], $Failed, Removed[JavaObject3722139521777665], Removed[JavaObject10184330554900481], Removed[JavaObject15229906854084609], Removed[JavaObject10275074959474689], Removed[JavaObject15592187211284481],
Removed[JavaObject22155425554104321], Removed[JavaObject9089030394216449], Removed[JavaObject34196997510529025], Removed[JavaObject35002742535618561], Removed[JavaObject35646965198880769], Removed[JavaObject6776183542775809], Removed[JavaObject1394708806893569],
Removed[JavaObject1631293657841665], Removed[JavaObject19127489783660545], Removed[JavaObject1823792011673601], Removed[JavaObject10028269680197633], Removed[JavaObject3591463682179073], Removed[JavaObject11334475619237889], Removed[JavaObject13425338293944321],
Removed[JavaObject33336335439757313], Removed[JavaObject31157552368582657], Removed[JavaObject9682765297483777], Removed[JavaObject29697961487237121], Removed[JavaObject24748448825737217], Removed[JavaObject783825693048833], Removed[JavaObject24748124924805121]},
False}]}
```

My main reason for using WW3 is the link to Egit. I may have to give up on that and do all git by hand I can't get this simple case to work correctly.

Mike (iqchef)

Comment: As to bug, I don't have Windows to test it, but it should be reported to WRI. As to Egit, you can use Workbench as plugin to Eclipse. I used instructions from [How to install the Wolfram Workbench plugin into Eclipse Kepler?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18183/14303), then updated Eclipse. Now I'm using Eclipse Luna with Workbench, Egit and tons of other plugins.

Comment: @jkuczm : I just heard back from them the fix was to install the lastest Eclipse and install their new pre-release Eclipse module. It's downloading now and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @ iqchef thanks.

Comment: I installed the Eclipse plugin they gave me into the newest Eclipse and the debugger works on my test file. Phew.

Comment: Well I attempted to do this all against with 11.0.1 and again debugging breakpoints won't stop during a debug test file execution. Same error as above. Wish they'd open the source up so we could do more than complain and actually fix the bug for free and give the answer back to Wolfram...

Comment: Have you tried the latest released version of "Workbench"? http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221, from my experience they've fixed a lot of the past issues. If this persists I'd report it to WRI

Comment: Yup... still fails