# Wolfram Workbench, Mathematica 11 and Eclipse Mars

Tags: workbench, eclipse

I'm new to Mathematica. I have to use it to be compliant with my new colleagues. I have available Eclipse Mars and Mathematica 11, there's a way to use Workbench? None of my colleagues use it or know it.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You need Eclipse Neon: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18184/5478

Comment: And you cannot upgrade from Eclipse Mars to Neon, so you have to first do a fresh installation of Eclipse Neon. Then you follow the instructions [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/27221).

Comment: I cannot upgrade to Neon do to security constraints on my PC.

Comment: Bad luck. You will have to fight with your IT department or use the not as powerful (in terms of error reporting and help document generation and MUnit-tests availabilty) but also nice https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin

Comment: If you are new to Mathematica, I strongly recommend you start by using the front end, and *not* Workbench.  Workbench is only useful for package development, something you probably wouldn't do for a while.  Also, Workbench isn't *necessary* for package development.

Comment: I just installed the new Workbench to work with mma 11. I developed my packages up to now with mma itself. Are there any examples how to use the workbench? Is there a simple hello world introduction?