# Creation of name.m Package

Tags: packages

I have a structure of folders.

1. Main Directory( has init.m, and name.m files)
2. Subfolders under Main directory

   1. library ( has the packages, pacakge1.m, package2.m)
   2. Data (some xcel sheets and other data files)
      The init.m has the following commands `Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"library", "Package1.m"}]];
      Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"library", "Package2.m"}]];`

Package1 has `function1` and `function2` definitions. Package2 has `function3` and `function4` definitions.

The Names.m file has the following the commands

```
Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"init.m"}]];
DeclarePackage["Package1`",{"function1", "function2"}];
DeclarePackage["Package2`",{"function3", "function4"}]
```

After evaluating the name.m file, I was expecting that calling `function1` should execute the `` Package1`function1 ``. However it is not happening. This is what I understand of *Mathematica* so far. I don't want to touch the init.m file in the Autoload folder of the userbase directory as I don't want to modify the contents. I just want my init.m in the local folder to run.

Workarounds anyone?

Comment: In the second argument of `BeginPackage` you can specify additional contexts/packages that are needed.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Play around with the function `FindFile` until you get the relationship between context name and folder structure. Both `\\package\\init.m`, or `\\package.m` are found with ``"package`"``, as long as the base directory is in the path, no need to specify the full file name. Subcontexts are interpreted as subfolders.

Comment: Somewhat [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14339/how-to-work-with-application-project-files-in-wolfram-workbench).

Comment: You can use `$InputFileName` instead of `NotebookDirectory[]` to refer to the filename of the currently evaluating .m file.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> NotebookDirectory[] gives the directory of the current evaluation notebook.

Your `init.m` is *not* the evaluation notebook and therefore this will not work. A simple test-case can be constructed when you create a `test.m` with a single line of code

```
Print[NotebookDirectory[]];
```

Then you open a new and *unsaved* notebook and `Get` this package. It will lead to an error

> `NotebookDirectory::nosv: The notebook NotebookObject[Untitled-1] is not saved. >>`

Why don't you look at the directory structure of packages in the e.g. `AddOns` folder and follow the usual conventions?