# What is the correct setup when using multiple packages in a Workbench Application project?

Tags: packages, workbench

With Workbench 3 I created an Application Project which resulted in the following directory/files tree.

```
Geometry (dir)
    Geometry (dir)
        Kernel (dir)
            init.m
        Geometry.m
    Geometry.nb
```

Sofar no problems.

Now, I have a package called Datasets.m with constants, datasets and utility functions. I inserted this file in the tree next to Geometry.m.

```
Geometry (dir)
    Geometry (dir)
        Kernel (dir)
            init.m
        Datasets.m
        Geometry.m
    Geometry.nb
```

When I do

```
<<Geometry`
```

in Geometry.nb no problems occur.

When I try to execute a function in Geometry.nb which uses a function in Geometry.m which itself uses a function in Datasets.m then the function in Datasets.m is not evaluated.

I found the following Q/A ["How to work with Application Project files in Wolfram Workbench?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14339/how-to-work-with-application-project-files-in-wolfram-workbench) but that did not solve my problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Setting the alignment between layout, contexts and public functions as [set out here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176591/2249) may help.

Comment: Thank you, will study this Q/A's carefully.